# Android Load activity into Class<?> object

Tags: java, android, instrumentation

so before I get into it, I'd like to describe my setup. Here is what I have:

1. A file called MainActivity.java which is a simple Activity class that has onCreate() method and a btnClick() method that executes a Toast message. That's it, nothing complicated. The package name for this MainActivity.java is com.testapp.
2. A file called LoadInst.java which is an Instrumentation class that tries to load the MainActivity.java into a Class object. THe package name for this is com.inst.

So what I"m trying to do is in the LoadInst.java class, I'm loading the MainActivity.java class into a Class object and then I create a method object to represent the onCreate() method in order to invoke the onCreate() method. The problem is that I get an Exception null thrown when on MainActivity.java onCreate() method tries to execute the line super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
I don't know if its because it is missing some information it needs in order to execute super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) properly.
Here is the code in my LoadInst.java which is extends to an Instrumentation class.

```
package com.inst;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class LoadInst extends Instrumentation {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
        super.onCreate(arguments);
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        String mainAct= "com.testapps.MainActivity";
        Looper.prepare();

        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(mainAct);
            Object obj = clazz.newInstance();

            Class onCreateParam[] = new Class[1];
            onCreateParam[0] = Bundle.class;

            Method onCreateMethod = Class.getDeclaredMethod("onCreate", onCreateParam);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            Log.d("TAG", "test: invoking onCreate()");
            onCreateMethod.setAccessible(true);
            onCreateMethod.invoke(obj, bundle);


        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, my goal is to create a generic Instrumentation class to perform tests on any target class. So, say I have app1. App1 is a simple android app that has one button and when you click on the button it executes a toast message. My goal is to use an instrumentation class, to load app1's main activity using Class and then call onCreate() method to make sure any objects/variables are initialized and then call the btnClick() method to execute the code inside that method (which in this case will be the toast message).

In other words, when I launch the instrumentation class, I would provide data using Bundle, so the instrumentation class would parse thru the bundle and extract, say, the target package, target class and the methods I want to execute for that target class.
Now I can load the class using Class and then I'm able to execute the btnClick() method, but the problem is that if there are objects/variables that are initialized during onCreate(), then the instrumentation class would fail if it invokes a method that uses one of those objects/variables that were initialized during onCreate().

Comment: Why you don't use the `Instrumentation callActivityOnCreate` method?

Comment: Hi, so I'm trying to find a way to load any activity class and execute methods that are specified for each activity. So I need to create a generic way of loading an activity and being able to execute whichever method I specify. So how can callActivityOnCreate() help me? How would I implement that in my code?

Comment: I've never used that class. When i saw your question I did a research on android documentation for [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html). You asked how call Activity onCreate method this is why I suggested this method.

Comment: Ahh.. gotcha. Unfortunately, the way I'm doing it above in the code doesn't seem to work properly. The onCreate() method is called, but for some weird reason it generates an error:
java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
I'm not exactly understanding that.

Comment: I wish I could help you, but do not understand what is your goal

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, I added more details about my goal in my original question below the code I posted. Could you please read it and see if it makes sense and provide any input? I could really use any ideas or other ways to achieve this if possible. Thanks!